# What does the regex (\d{3})(?=\d) mean?

Tags: ruby, regex, expression

I am new to regex, and I am trying to break down the regex so I can understand it better:

```
 /(\d{3})(?=\d)/
```

I understand that `(\d{3})` is capturing 3 digits, but unsure what the second portion is trying to capture.

What does `?=` mean?

Comment: You can test the regex [here][1].
Its not a real answer on what you want but still helpfull.


  [1]: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(?=\d)` is a [**positive lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) it means match & capture 3 digits that are followed by a digit.

So  something like this will happen:

```
1234 => capture 123
123a => no match
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So for a code like:

number.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/, '\1,')

This is capturing all the 3 digits and ensuring that there is at least one digit following it. If true, then sub in a ",".

If you don't mind, can you explain "\1" I tried researching this on google but the explanations were difficult for me to make sense of.

Comment: `\1` is actually back reference to captured group #1. So `1234` will become `123,4`

Answer (score 2):

`(?=pat)` - *Positive lookahead assertion*: ensures that the following characters match pat, but doesn't include those characters in the matched text

`/(\d{3})(?=\d)/` - Here `(\d{3})` is capturing 3 digits, followed by a digit,but last digit not to be captured in that group.

Look [here](http://rubular.com/r/bkrRkJ7UNO), [here](http://rubular.com/r/MUZasas5U8) and [here](http://rubular.com/r/aBspKgiesy)

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and thank you for putting together the rubular for me :)